# Neo4j entire graph not being loading into pagecache

Tags: caching, memory-management, neo4j

**tldr:** Big neo4j dataset, trying to load into page cache. Only a part of the db being loaded. Queries with count very slow. Sysinfo and memrec showing different db data volumes. **How to load the entire graph into memory, and reduce db hit counts?**

I have a 25G 3.5.12 Enterprise Neo4j Database, running on a 52G server. Currently I have set the page cache to be 28G, and heap size to be 12G in the conf file. I want to load the entire dataset into cache for fast querying.

**The problem:**

**1.** Even after warming up with `apoc.warmup.run(true, true, true)`, my queries are still hitting the database millions of times. I have also tried the basic `MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) RETURN count(r), count(n.name)` etc., but the same problem persists.

Here is the post apoc warmup result:

[image: Post Apoc Warmup Result]

This is a sample profile query:

[image: Profile for a basic fetch query]

**2.**  Another very hard to understand thing is that memrec and sysinfo seem to be showing different results.

Memrec says I have 7.7G data volume, and indexes, while sysinfo and du say I have 25G.

sysinfo:

[image: Sysinfo]

memrec:

[image: Memrec]

`du -ach`:
[image]

Exactly as the numbers indicated by memrec, the system is only using approx. 8G + 12G(Heap) from neo4j :

[image: htop]

**May someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here? How can I get all the graph nodes and relationships in the page cache?**